# hplip proper installation (linux)

Tags: linux, drivers, network-printer

Trying to print to an HP PhotoSmart printer from linux, all paths seem to lead to hplip. The hplip installer tells you not to install as root but instead prompts for a root password. In 20 years of administering linux I have never once keyed in my root password to a third party script or application. Is there another installation path I'm overlooking, or has it become common practice to entrust installed applications with the keys to the shop?

Comment: Sounds about par for the course to me, TBH.  (Software developers with abhorrent coding practices that makes their software incompatible with anything resembling security practices by their customers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `sudo hp-setup` to force the account into a root context and allow it to run with sufficient permissions. There are details at [Configure your printer using hp-setup](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/manual/hp_setup.html)

How is running an application as root different from giving it the password? You have either given away the keys, or escorted the suspect into the inner sanctum. The likelihood that you would be able to review the install application comprehensively enough to confirm no bad things can happen is vanishingly small.

I fully agree in principle, but only if the application exposes a complete list of ACL details that it requires, and you create a user with those specific roles, you can't be certain that there is unexpected access. Even then, it requires ridiculous levels of diligence.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I got sidetracked onto something else. I used hp-setup and it successfully configured the older version of the driver from the yum (fedora) package repository. Hopefully this will work fine. I was trying to install the newer one from HP using their instructions. My question remains for doing that.

Comment: There is a profound difference between letting an application run as root and giving it the root password. The latter should never be necessary and exposes sensitive information that doesn't need to be exposed. The real question is why it would need the actual password when sudo is the commonly accepted practice. It smacks of software incompetence, which is all the more reason not to entrust it with sensitive information.